# Raspberry Pi C++11 std::thread: pure virtual method called

Tags: gcc, c++, arm, raspberrypi, cross-compilation

Ubuntu 14.04. I've installed gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf, g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf (tried 4.8 and 4.9 from utopic).

Code that uses std::thread:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>

void secondList()
{
    const std::chrono::seconds twoSeconds(2);

    for (size_t i = 0; i != 300; ++i)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(twoSeconds);
        std::cout << "2s\n";
    }
}

int main(int, const char *[])
{
    auto secondThr = std::async(std::launch::async, secondList);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ --std=c++11 main.cpp -lpthread -o main
```

On RPI it fails:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ./main 
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted
```

Compiling on RPI works:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ g++ --std=c++0x main.cpp -lpthread -o main
```

Pi image 2015-02-16-raspbian-wheezy, g++ on Pi (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1) 4.6.3.

I've tried compiler options `-mcpu=cortex-a7`, `-mcpu=cortex-a8` and `-D__GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_{1,2,4,8}` that were mentioned in similar questions.

Also tried g++ from ppa: http://ppa.launchpad.net/linaro-maintainers/toolchain/ubuntu precise

Why it is happening and how to get a cross-compiler that works?

Comment: I think this is a pure programming question and should be asked on [so].

Comment: I think this is much more about the compiler than the language and programming. That's *fairly* Ubuntu IMO.

Comment: People on stackoverflow have no idea. The most voted answers are like "take toolchain from some git repository, compile it and then rsync to /lib and /usr on Pi". It is horrible since the g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf almost works both for Pi and bq phone except for that locking bug on Pi.

Comment: Velkan I don't see a post from you on SO. @Oli SO also encompasses the tools involved in programming - including the compiler.

Comment: Is this a Raspberry Pi 1 or 2? Also, what is the output of "uname -a" on the Pi? Not all kernels are hard-float (the "hf" in "armhf").

Comment: It is 2. Btw, I am going for newer OS image. I make an answer when I'll be sure. Seems like that old wheezy image libraries are built incorrectly and they've made a workaround in their custom toolchain.

Comment: @muru That this would be on-topic on another SE site [is not sufficient to make it off-topic here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/). As Oli says, this seems to be a tool question, which means it should probably be considered on-topic both on Ask Ubuntu and on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @EliahKagan I don't think that being a tool question necessarily makes it on-topic here, but I do think that being a tool question necessarily makes it on-topic on [so].

Comment: Did you solve it? I have exactly the same problem! I'm using OSX cross compile to pi 3 model B (Jessie Raspbarian).

Comment: @Alston, nothing more than in http://askubuntu.com/a/665000/391744

Comment: I solved it by changing flags from "-march=armv8-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon" to "-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With jessie-based image it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not work on my jessie-based image. I'm cross compile from OSX, it seems it's compiler's bug.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to the command line for linking,

`-Wl,--whole-archive -lpthread -Wl,--no-whole-archive`

See this message for explanations, https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2010-05/msg00029.html It said to be a problem of TLS, but maybe it's related incomplete symbols linked from static `libpthread`.

Answer (score -1):

It can probably be fixed by adding  `-D__GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_1 -D__GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_2 -D__GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_8` to the command line flags.

The root cause and fix are described here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/48225/whats-causing-these-crashes-after-cross-compiling